# Bootstrap-Modal, Modal not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using [Bootstrap-modal](https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal) because my client thinks that the regular modal from Twitter Bootstrap is not good enough for him.

So I have been successful in modifying in recreating a simple test to use the full width modal, isolated on a separate page. However when I drop that code into my existing page and click on the modal, I get nothing but a white overlay. The contents of the modal are on the page they are just not showing up.

It's either late or I don't know enough javascript / css to understand this.

The page / code can be found here. In the middle right side is a blue "view demo" button.

http://dev.garadise.com/product/speakers1/1

Comment: I think it's not loading the class="modal". Only loading the class="modal-backdrop".

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap then you have to change your code you current code is

```
<button class="demo btn btn-primary btn-large" data-toggle="modal" href="#full-width">View Demo</button>
```

remove href and put data-target="#full-width" then your code become

```
<button class="demo btn btn-primary btn-large" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#full-width">View Demo</button>
```

check this for more info

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Didn't work, I'm not using the traditional Twitter bootstrap modal. I'm using github / twitter bootstrap extenstion.

Comment: I checked your page source code there is no div with id #full-width that y it's not opening

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see your current code on the button is currect with data-target not href.
I think you have put a "hide" class to the modal. That what's hiding the modal also when it's opened. Just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Might be following 2 problems:

1. improper css or css having error,
2. improper js or js having error

I had same problem when I was beginner of bootstrap. Just download proper css and js from official bootstrap site and use it.